# Update manager not working gdm2setup?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Keep getting this error,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gdm2setup/gdm2setup/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gdm2setup/gdm2setup/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are no packages for Precise in this PPA, only for Karmic and Lucid. Remove it from your software sources.

Comment: Start Software Centre, open "Software Sources" in the "Edit" menu, go to the "Other Software" tab, mark the lines for this PPA and hit the "Remove" button.

Comment: Pretty easy. I am really digging Ubuntu!!!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is to install the LIM utility for the new GDM, then

[Take a look here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gdm2-setup-a-login-interface-management-utility-for-the-new-gdm.html)